# Is it possible to use #define inside a function?

Tags: c++, c

For example, I saw source code like the following. Can we use `#define` in a function? How does it work? (more information: this code is what I copied from `openvswitch` source code):

```
void *
ofputil_put_action(enum ofputil_action_code code, struct ofpbuf *buf)
{
switch (code) {
case OFPUTIL_ACTION_INVALID:

#define OFPAT13_ACTION(ENUM, STRUCT, EXTENSIBLE, NAME) case OFPUTIL_##ENUM:
#include "ofp-util.def"
    OVS_NOT_REACHED();

#define OFPAT10_ACTION(ENUM, STRUCT, NAME)                  \
case OFPUTIL_##ENUM: return ofputil_put_##ENUM(buf);
#define OFPAT11_ACTION(ENUM, STRUCT, EXTENSIBLE, NAME)      \
case OFPUTIL_##ENUM: return ofputil_put_##ENUM(buf);
#define NXAST_ACTION(ENUM, STRUCT, EXTENSIBLE, NAME)        \
case OFPUTIL_##ENUM: return ofputil_put_##ENUM(buf);
#include "ofp-util.def"
}
OVS_NOT_REACHED();
}

#define OFPAT10_ACTION(ENUM, STRUCT, NAME)                        \
void                                                        \
ofputil_init_##ENUM(struct STRUCT *s)                       \
{                                                           \
    memset(s, 0, sizeof *s);                                \
    s->type = htons(ENUM);                                  \
    s->len = htons(sizeof *s);                              \
}                                                           \
                                                            \
struct STRUCT *                                             \
ofputil_put_##ENUM(struct ofpbuf *buf)                      \
{                                                           \
    struct STRUCT *s = ofpbuf_put_uninit(buf, sizeof *s);   \
    ofputil_init_##ENUM(s);                                 \
    return s;                                               \
}
#define OFPAT11_ACTION(ENUM, STRUCT, EXTENSIBLE, NAME) \
OFPAT10_ACTION(ENUM, STRUCT, NAME)
#define OFPAT13_ACTION(ENUM, STRUCT, EXTENSIBLE, NAME) \
OFPAT10_ACTION(ENUM, STRUCT, NAME)
#define NXAST_ACTION(ENUM, STRUCT, EXTENSIBLE, NAME)            \
void                                                        \
ofputil_init_##ENUM(struct STRUCT *s)                       \
{                                                           \
    memset(s, 0, sizeof *s);                                \
    s->type = htons(OFPAT10_VENDOR);                        \
    s->len = htons(sizeof *s);                              \
    s->vendor = htonl(NX_VENDOR_ID);                        \
    s->subtype = htons(ENUM);                               \
}                                                           \
                                                            \
struct STRUCT *                                             \
ofputil_put_##ENUM(struct ofpbuf *buf)                      \
{                                                           \
    struct STRUCT *s = ofpbuf_put_uninit(buf, sizeof *s);   \
    ofputil_init_##ENUM(s);                                 \
    return s;                                               \
}
#include "ofp-util.def"
```

Comment: I want to know what the programmer was smoking when that code was written

Comment: @EdHeal http://www.incrediblethings.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/squid-blunt-1.jpg

Comment: Please describe what it is you'd like to accomplish by using #define.  If you question is "will a program with a #define inside a function definition compile?" then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`#define` **is a preprocessor directive**: it is used to generate the eventual C++ code **before it is handled to the compiler** that will generate an executable. Therefore code like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 54; i++) {
  #define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
}
```

is **not** executed 54 times (at the preprocessor level): the preprocessor simply runs over the `for` loop (not knowing what a `for` loop is), sees a define statement, associates `1024` with `BUFFER_SIZE` and continues. Until it reaches the bottom of the file.

You can write `#define` everywhere since the preprocessor is not really aware of the program itself.

Answer (score 11):

Sure this is possible. The `#define` is processed by the preprocessor before the compiler does anything. It is a simple text replacement. The preprocessor doesn't even know if the line of code is inside or outside a function, class or whatever.

By the way, it is generally considered bad style to define preprocessor macros in C++. Most of the things they are used for can be better achieved with templates.

Answer (score 7):

You can use it inside a function, but it is not scoped to the function.  So, in your example, the second definitions of a macro will be a redefinition and generate an error.  You need to use `#undef` to clear them first.

Comment: I'm a little unsure about introducing *scope* in this. As the preprocessor simply (pre)processes the file as plain text, top to bottom, all it sees are #define's, items to replace, and yes, #undef's. It is *not* aware of 'functions' - you can #define and #undef multiple times inside (or outside) a single function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `#define` anywhere you want. It has no knowledge of functions and is not bound by their scope. As the preprocessor scans the file from top-to-bottom it processes `#define`s as it sees them. Do not be misled (by silly code like this!) into thinking that the `#define` is somehow processed only when the function is called; it's not.

Comment: isnt all #define processed in beginning ?

Comment: @Fawad They're expanded by the _preprocessor_ while it _preprocesses_ your source, which occurs at the beginning of your build, before the compilation stage, yes.

Answer (score 3):

How does it work? All C/C++ files are first processed by... the *preprocessor*.

It doesn't know anything about C nor C++ syntax. It simply replaces `THIS_THING` with `ANOTHER THING`. That's why you can place a `#define` in functions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.   `#define` is handled by the preprocessor which occurs well before the compiler has any sense of lines of code being inside functions, inside parameters lists, inside data structures, etc.

Since the preprocessor has no concept of C++ functions, it also means that there is no natural scope to macro definitions.  So if you want to reuse a macro name, you have to `#undef NAME` to avoid warnings.