# Define macro value in function

Tags: c

Below two programs give different results. I thought these two program should give the same result as 20..20 because macro define is in the fun(), it should not affect outside of fun(). Can you explain the reasons?

A: result is 20..20

```
# include <stdio.h>
# define i 20
void fun();
main()
{
    printf("%d..", i);
    fun();
    printf("%d", i);
}

void fun()
{
    #undef i 
    #define i 30 
}
```

B: result is 30..30

```
# include <stdio.h>
# define i 20

void fun()
{
#undef i 
#define i 30 
}

main()
{
    printf("%d..", i);
    fun();
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Comment: Macro definition are globally. It doesn't care if you define it in the function or not. The preprocessor will replace the first occurrence of the macro and will go on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C Preprocessor is not a part of the compiler, but is a separate step in the compilation process.

Now, because it's a separate step in the compilation process, it's not the same as assigning `i` with different values. When your code runs, it treats `i` as `20` because that was defined before `main`. But, as I said,it's a separate step, **and** it does not care about functions scope, so, there is *before main* (`i=20`) and *after main* (`i=30`). When the Preprocessor  runs it treats the whole scope as global.

Try using the `#define` inside the main, not in a function, and check what happens...

Example:

```
void f(){
    #define a 5
    printf("%d\n", a);
    #undef a
    #define a 10
    printf("%d\n", a);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", a); // a can be printed even though f() was never called!!
    #define i 20
    printf("%d\n", i); // 20
    #undef i
    #define i 30
    printf("%d\n", i); // 30! :)
    return 0;
}
```

You can find more info in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968567/is-it-possible-to-use-define-inside-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

defines are preprocessed before the compilation and they are global. If you want to assign a value in the function just use normal C assign operator & the a global variable,.